Why is my simple content-visibility demo not working as expected?
I'm trying to make a clone of this demo, but it's not working for me.
Here's what I have so far:
CSS:
.container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  contain: strict;
  contain-intrinsic-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
tr {
  height: 21px;
  contain: strict;
  contain-intrinsic-height: auto 21px;
  content-visibility: auto;
}

HTML:
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jesterly/pen/JjqrbaY
How come it doesn't appear to be working? In the stackblitz demo, the rows that are outside of the viewable area have a "Descendants are skipped due to content-visibility" tooltip when you hover over them in the inspector (in Edge), but in my demo I get no such tooltip, which is why I think my demo isn't working as expected. What am I doing wrong? I'm just trying to wrap my head around this new CSS property.
UPDATE: I finally got it to work by changing the table to a grid via CSS. Strange, I guess content-visibility doesn't work on tables. 
Revised CSS:
.container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  contain: strict;
  contain-intrinsic-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
table,
tbody {
  display: block;
}
tr {
  contain: strict;
  contain-intrinsic-height: auto 21px;
  content-visibility: auto;
  display: grid;
}


You have tried to archive the same as the StackBlitz demo. Below is the example how you can archive this:


.container {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-height: 300px;
    contain: strict;
    contain-intrinsic-height: 300px;
}

 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;

    & thead {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      background: #fff;
      display: block;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    & tbody {
      display: block;
    }

    & tr {
      display: grid;
      width: 100%;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      contain: strict;
      content-visibility: auto;
      contain-intrinsic-height: auto 42px;
    }

    & tr,
    & th,
    & td {
      text-align: left;
      max-height: 42px;
    }
    
    & th,
    & td {
      padding: 12px;
      display: block;
    }
  }
<div class="container">
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Head</th>
          <th>Head</th>
          <th>Head</th>
          <th>Head</th>
          <th>Head</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>  
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td></tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>




Yes. The problem is when I tried to replicate it without using Lit it's not producing the same results. How did you embed the content like that? I didn't see this option when I posted the question.

@jesterly, When you edit the question you can find the code symbol like this: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/48736511?key=e2354ae4d73ab334fb13d93221e2c0a6

I can't believe I missed that -- thanks!
